# How to make CMake use gnu17 C standard instead of ISO C17

Tags: c, gcc, cmake

I am trying to force CMake to pass std=gnu17 instead of std=c17 to GCC.
I tried:

```
set_property(TARGET "${MyProject_${Compile_Type}_NAME}" PROPERTY C_STANDARD gnu17)
```

in the CMakeLists.txt but I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:260 (add_executable):
C_STANDARD is set to invalid value 'gnu17'
```

The same happens when I try gnu11 instead of gnu17.
The reason I want it to pass the flag is that I am using one of the GCC extensions and that produces a warning when using -pedantic warning levels (which I would prefer to keep using).
Please notice this is specifically about C, not C++.

Comment: If the [manual](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/C_STANDARD.html) is correct, using `17` _should_ set it to `gnu17`. If not, I guess you have to set the flag manually.

Comment: @tkausl Yes I have seen this and was surprised by the behavior. At least under WSL2 running Ubuntu it's not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, CMake will use `-std=gnu17` with plain `C_STANDARD 17`.
But if you want to be sure that CMake will use compiler-specific extensions, then you may set also [C_EXTENSIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/C_EXTENSIONS.html) property:

```
set_target_properties(<...> PROPERTIES
  C_STANDARD 17
  C_EXTENSIONS ON
)
```

---

If your code works only with a specific compiler and its extentions, then you probably want to also check a compiler:

```
if (NOT CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU")
  message(FATAL_ERROR "The project requires g++ to be used as C++ compiler"
endif()
```

Comment: Maybe it's about it being run in WSL2 with Ubuntu 22.04 but I am getting: Error at CMakeLists.txt:260 (add_executable):
  C_STANDARD is set to invalid value 'gnu11' when I try gnu11 or gnu17 options. When I tree C_EXENTSIONS_ON then it works but nothing happens (still warnings on standard GNU extenstions). It's Cmake 3.25.1. It just works on Windows with MinGW so I am probably doing something wrong there but can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Oops, I meant C_STANDARD being set to 17, not to gnu17. The answer is fixed now. BTW, you could always check the exact compiler command line being executed. With "Unix Makefiles" generator (when you use `make` for build the project) it can be done with `make VERBOSE=1`.